# PHP log exception on AWS Beanstalk

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, apache, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am deploying a PHP application with elasticbeanstlak. The application is a website deployed on Apache Server.

The issue is that, after the deployment, when accessing the deployed app url i get this error

```
Zend_log_exception with message "/usr/local/var/log/apache2/www.test.com/application.log cannot be opened with mode a
```

How to solve this issue ?  I tried to use the containers command but it doesn't seem to work..

Comment: Hi did you check if the folder '/usr/local/var/log/apache2/www.test.com/' exists on the underlying ec2 instance?

Comment: no it doesn't exist, actually I am looking for a command to create it if it doesnt exist

Comment: If you created/selected a key pair when creating the application on beanstalk then you can ssh (or use the connect button if it is an amazon linux 2) to the instance and run this command: ```sudo mkdir -p /usr/local/var/log/apache2/www.test.com/```.

The best way to handle this in the futur is to create a file named 'my_script.config' with the command as follows:


```#!/bin/sh  
sudo mkdir mkdir -p /usr/local/var/log/apache2/www.test.com/  
```
  

(I'm not sure if you need the sudo though).

Comment: I forgot to mention the use of beanstalk extensions: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/ebextensions.html for the config script. An other 'dirty' option is to include a script in your app that creates the folder.